# Вывести на печать 2 листа

Tags: c#, winforms

как можно перенести на 2 лист, где: Нижняя челюсть - Левая сторона от 44, хочу перенести на 2 лист. Но как можно сделать?

```
private void printDocument1_PrintPage(object sender, System.Drawing.Printing.PrintPageEventArgs e)
    {
        // int currentPage = 0;



        e.Graphics.DrawString("Пациент: "+labelControl42.Text, new Font("Times New Roman", 14, FontStyle.Bold), Brushes.Black, new PointF(50,20));

        //Верхняя челюсть - Левая сторона
        {
            e.Graphics.DrawString(groupControl2.Text, new Font("Times New Roman", 14, FontStyle.Bold), Brushes.Black, new PointF(50, 60));
            e.Graphics.DrawString("18-" + comboBoxEdit1.SelectedItem.ToString(), new Font("Times New Roman", 12, FontStyle.Italic), Brushes.Black, new PointF(50, 85));
            e.Graphics.DrawImage(pictureEdit10.Image, new PointF(50, 105));
            //////////////////////////////////////////////////
            e.Graphics.DrawString("17-" + comboBoxEdit2.SelectedItem.ToString(), new Font("Times New Roman", 12, FontStyle.Italic), Brushes.Black, new PointF(290, 85));
            e.Graphics.DrawImage(pictureEdit11.Image, new PointF(290, 105));
            /////////////////////////////////////////////////
            e.Graphics.DrawString("16-" + comboBoxEdit3.SelectedItem.ToString(), new Font("Times New Roman", 12, FontStyle.Italic), Brushes.Black, new PointF(530, 85));
            e.Graphics.DrawImage(pictureEdit12.Image, new PointF(530, 105));
            /////////////////////////////////////////////////
            e.Graphics.DrawString("15-" + comboBoxEdit4.SelectedItem.ToString(), new Font("Times New Roman", 12, FontStyle.Italic), Brushes.Black, new PointF(760, 85));
            e.Graphics.DrawImage(pictureEdit13.Image, new PointF(760, 105));

            e.Graphics.DrawString("14-" + comboBoxEdit5.SelectedItem.ToString(), new Font("Times New Roman", 12, FontStyle.Italic), Brushes.Black, new PointF(50, 185));
            e.Graphics.DrawImage(pictureEdit14.Image, new PointF(50, 205));
            ////////////////////////////////////////////////
            e.Graphics.DrawString("13-" + comboBoxEdit6.SelectedItem.ToString(), new Font("Times New Roman", 12, FontStyle.Italic), Brushes.Black, new PointF(290, 185));
            e.Graphics.DrawImage(pictureEdit15.Image, new PointF(290, 205));
            ///////////////////////////////////////////////
            e.Graphics.DrawString("12-" + comboBoxEdit7.SelectedItem.ToString(), new Font("Times New Roman", 12, FontStyle.Italic), Brushes.Black, new PointF(530, 185));
            e.Graphics.DrawImage(pictureEdit16.Image, new PointF(530, 205));
            //////////////////////////////////////////////
            e.Graphics.DrawString("11-" + comboBoxEdit8.SelectedItem.ToString(), new Font("Times New Roman", 12, FontStyle.Italic), Brushes.Black, new PointF(760, 185));
            e.Graphics.DrawImage(pictureEdit17.Image, new PointF(760, 205));
        }

        //Верхняя челюсть - Правая сторона
        {
            e.Graphics.DrawString(groupControl3.Text, new Font("Times New Roman", 14, FontStyle.Bold), Brushes.Black, new PointF(50, 335));
            e.Graphics.DrawString("21-" + comboBoxEdit16.SelectedItem.ToString(), new Font("Times New Roman", 12, FontStyle.Italic), Brushes.Black, new PointF(50, 360));
            e.Graphics.DrawImage(pictureEdit25.Image, new PointF(50, 380));
            //////////////////////////////////////////////
            e.Graphics.DrawString("22-" + comboBoxEdit15.SelectedItem.ToString(), new Font("Times New Roman", 12, FontStyle.Italic), Brushes.Black, new PointF(290, 360));
            e.Graphics.DrawImage(pictureEdit24.Image, new PointF(290, 380));
            /////////////////////////////////////////////
            e.Graphics.DrawString("23-" + comboBoxEdit14.SelectedItem.ToString(), new Font("Times New Roman", 12, FontStyle.Italic), Brushes.Black, new PointF(530, 360));
            e.Graphics.DrawImage(pictureEdit23.Image, new PointF(530, 380));
            ////////////////////////////////////////////
            e.Graphics.DrawString("24-" + comboBoxEdit13.SelectedItem.ToString(), new Font("Times New Roman", 12, FontStyle.Italic), Brushes.Black, new PointF(760, 360));
            e.Graphics.DrawImage(pictureEdit22.Image, new PointF(760, 380));
            ///////////////////////////////////////////
            e.Graphics.DrawString("25-" + comboBoxEdit12.SelectedItem.ToString(), new Font("Times New Roman", 12, FontStyle.Italic), Brushes.Black, new PointF(50, 470));
            e.Graphics.DrawImage(pictureEdit21.Image, new PointF(50, 490));
            ///////////////////////////////////////////
            e.Graphics.DrawString("26-" + comboBoxEdit11.SelectedItem.ToString(), new Font("Times New Roman", 12, FontStyle.Italic), Brushes.Black, new PointF(290, 470));
            e.Graphics.DrawImage(pictureEdit20.Image, new PointF(290, 490));
            ///////////////////////////////////////////
            e.Graphics.DrawString("27-" + comboBoxEdit10.SelectedItem.ToString(), new Font("Times New Roman", 12, FontStyle.Italic), Brushes.Black, new PointF(530, 470));
            e.Graphics.DrawImage(pictureEdit19.Image, new PointF(530, 490));
            //////////////////////////////////////////
            e.Graphics.DrawString("28-" + comboBoxEdit9.SelectedItem.ToString(), new Font("Times New Roman", 12, FontStyle.Italic), Brushes.Black, new PointF(760, 470));
            e.Graphics.DrawImage(pictureEdit18.Image, new PointF(760, 490));
        }

        //Нижняя челюсть - Левая сторона
        {
            e.Graphics.DrawString(groupControl4.Text, new Font("Times New Roman", 14, FontStyle.Bold), Brushes.Black, new PointF(50, 600));
            e.Graphics.DrawString("48-" + comboBoxEdit24.SelectedItem.ToString(), new Font("Times New Roman", 12, FontStyle.Italic), Brushes.Black, new PointF(50, 625));
            e.Graphics.DrawImage(pictureEdit33.Image, new PointF(50, 645));
            /////////////////////////////////////////
            e.Graphics.DrawString("47-" + comboBoxEdit23.SelectedItem.ToString(), new Font("Times New Roman", 12, FontStyle.Italic), Brushes.Black, new PointF(290, 625));
            e.Graphics.DrawImage(pictureEdit32.Image, new PointF(290, 645));
            /////////////////////////////////////////
            e.Graphics.DrawString("46-" + comboBoxEdit22.SelectedItem.ToString(), new Font("Times New Roman", 12, FontStyle.Italic), Brushes.Black, new PointF(530, 625));
            e.Graphics.DrawImage(pictureEdit31.Image, new PointF(530, 645));
            /////////////////////////////////////////
            e.Graphics.DrawString("45-" + comboBoxEdit21.SelectedItem.ToString(), new Font("Times New Roman", 12, FontStyle.Italic), Brushes.Black, new PointF(760, 625));
            e.Graphics.DrawImage(pictureEdit30.Image, new PointF(760, 645));

            //Этот часть я хочу перенести на 2 лист
            /////////////////////////////////////////
            e.Graphics.DrawString("44-" + comboBoxEdit21.SelectedItem.ToString(), new Font("Times New Roman", 12, FontStyle.Italic), Brushes.Black, new PointF(760, 625));
            e.Graphics.DrawImage(pictureEdit30.Image, new PointF(860, 645));
            /////////////////////////////////////////
            e.Graphics.DrawString("43-" + comboBoxEdit21.SelectedItem.ToString(), new Font("Times New Roman", 12, FontStyle.Italic), Brushes.Black, new PointF(760, 625));
            e.Graphics.DrawImage(pictureEdit30.Image, new PointF(960, 645));
            /////////////////////////////////////////
            e.Graphics.DrawString("42-" + comboBoxEdit21.SelectedItem.ToString(), new Font("Times New Roman", 12, FontStyle.Italic), Brushes.Black, new PointF(760, 625));
            e.Graphics.DrawImage(pictureEdit30.Image, new PointF(1060, 645));
            /////////////////////////////////////////
            e.Graphics.DrawString("41-" + comboBoxEdit21.SelectedItem.ToString(), new Font("Times New Roman", 12, FontStyle.Italic), Brushes.Black, new PointF(760, 625));
            e.Graphics.DrawImage(pictureEdit30.Image, new PointF(1160, 645));
        }
    }
```

Буду благодарен!